# Why the selection is wrong when file input is hidden?

Tags: jquery

I was 100% sure this code works, but in one special case it fails - spent an hour to find the bug (could not reproduce it on JSFiddle). Finally I found the cause, but I do not know why this happens. It happens only when I hide the file inputs and the result is: whichever file I change the first label is selected and changed, please take a look:

```js
var activateFileSelection = function( container ) {
    var container = container || $('body');
    container.find(':file').each(function(i) {
        var thisInput = $(this);
        var thisLabel = thisInput.siblings('label');
        if (thisLabel.length > 0 && !thisLabel.hasClass('file-input-label')) {
            var thisLabelDefaultText = thisLabel.html();
            thisLabel.addClass('file-input-label');
            thisInput.on('change', function(e) {
                if (thisInput.val()) {
                    thisLabel.html(thisInput.val());
                } else {
                    thisLabel.html(thisLabelDefaultText);
                };
            });
        };
    });
};
activateFileSelection();
```

```css
input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="myfile">select 1</label>
    <input id="myfile" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="myfile">select 2</label>
    <input id="myfile" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="myfile">select 3</label>
    <input id="myfile" type="file" />
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzj9q01L/3/).

If the input is not hidden, everything works fine: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzj9q01L/4/).

As [nevermind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2045185/nevermind) noted below, duplicate input IDs may have something with the issue, still in script I do not address and IDs. Also, the change of each file input triggers the change of label text, but wrong one.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xzj9q01L/5/ Change ids and labels... no duplicated ids!

Comment: I do not use IDs in my code. I need an explanation why this works with visible inputs, but not with invisible. What visible/invisible inputs have to do with IDs?

Comment: I am afraid that i don't understand problem then, after renaming of id's and labels, all works fine...check fiddle.

Comment: The code above is a part of ticket app, each input is in its own form and it worked previous years. But now I've hidden the inputs and it stopped working, so the question is (as stated above): Why the code does not work with hidden inputs? I am really not clever enough.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add unique IDs or are you just curious as to why?

Comment: I already added unique IDs, but I am curious to know why this happens, because the code as is has to work same no matter if element is hidden or not. There must be something else behind it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The layout of the HTML code may suggest that each label is linked to the input field next to it, but it is not the case. Since the `for` attribute of the three labels is `"myfile"`, all three labels are in fact linked to the first input field, the one that is found with `document.getElementById("myfile")`.

Therefore, when you click on any label, the first input field is used. The adjacent label, obtained with `thisInput.siblings('label')` in your code, is then updated after the file selection. That is true even when the 3 input fields are visible.

On the other hand, if you click directly on an input field, that input field is used and the corresponding label is updated.

The following snippet sends a message to the console to indicate which file input is used.

```js
var activateFileSelection = function (container) {
    var container = container || $('body');
    container.find(':file').each(function (i) {
        var thisInput = $(this);
        var thisLabel = thisInput.siblings('label');
        if (thisLabel.length > 0 && !thisLabel.hasClass('file-input-label')) {
            var thisLabelDefaultText = thisLabel.html();
            thisLabel.addClass('file-input-label');
            thisInput.on('change', function (e) {
                console.log("Input used: " + thisInput.data("field"));
                if (thisInput.val()) {
                    thisLabel.html(thisInput.val());
                } else {
                    thisLabel.html(thisLabelDefaultText);
                };
            });
        };
    });
};
activateFileSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test by clicking on label 3 vs clicking on input field 3:</p>
<div>
    <label for="myfile">select 1</label>
    <input id="myfile" type="file" data-field="input1" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="myfile">select 2</label>
    <input id="myfile" type="file" data-field="input2" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="myfile">select 3</label>
    <input id="myfile" type="file" data-field="input3" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you look at my code, you see I select the label with `siblings()` jQuery method. How the sibling method can select first label? Ah, I see, let me check it.

Comment: Right, thanks man, was so confusing, couldn't see wood for the trees...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the proper ID for your label.

```js
var activateFileSelection = function( container ) {
    var container = container || $('body');
    container.find(':file').each(function(i) {
        var thisInput = $(this);
        var thisLabel = thisInput.siblings('label');
        if (thisLabel.length > 0 && !thisLabel.hasClass('file-input-label')) {
            var thisLabelDefaultText = thisLabel.html();
            thisLabel.addClass('file-input-label');
            thisInput.on('change', function(e) {
                if (thisInput.val()) {
                    thisLabel.html(thisInput.val());
                } else {
                    thisLabel.html(thisLabelDefaultText);
                };
            });
        };
    });
};
activateFileSelection();
```

```css
input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="myfile1">select 1</label>
    <input id="myfile1" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="myfile2">select 2</label>
    <input id="myfile2" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="myfile3">select 3</label>
    <input id="myfile3" type="file" />
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I understand your question now. I'm not sure what the cause is. It's likely just a bug with how the browser interprets it is my guess. The proper way to do it is to add unique IDs.

Comment: OP, please note that this answer was first. I was writing mine as this was posted. If either answer solves your issue, please mark this one as the answer as it was first.

Comment: I can also guess it may be the browser or jQuery core, but I do not want to guess, I really want accurate answer. Sorry, but your answer is not the one I want.

Comment: I realize it's not what you want but I just didn't delete my answer, instead edited in I realize what you want now. It looks like someone else has found the (maybe) correct answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the duplicate ID's. Since they are all the same, the change is made to the first instance of that ID. Changing the ID's fixes the issue:

```js
var activateFileSelection = function( container ) {
    var container = container || $('body');
    container.find(':file').each(function(i) {
        var thisInput = $(this);
        var thisLabel = thisInput.siblings('label');
        if (thisLabel.length > 0 && !thisLabel.hasClass('file-input-label')) {
            var thisLabelDefaultText = thisLabel.html();
            thisLabel.addClass('file-input-label');
            thisInput.on('change', function(e) {
                if (thisInput.val()) {
                    thisLabel.html(thisInput.val());
                } else {
                    thisLabel.html(thisLabelDefaultText);
                };
            });
        };
    });
};
activateFileSelection();
```

```css
input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="myfile1">select 1</label>
    <input id="myfile1" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="myfile2">select 2</label>
    <input id="myfile2" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="myfile3">select 3</label>
    <input id="myfile3" type="file" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why the script works with duplicate IDs when the inputs are not hidden than?

Answer (score 0):

I replace the events for label

Trigger based on what we need.

```
var activateFileSelection = function (container) {
    var container = container || $('body');
    container.find(':file').each(function (i) {
        var thisInput = $(this);
        var thisLabel = thisInput.siblings('label');
        if (thisLabel.length > 0 && !thisLabel.hasClass('file-input-label')) {
            var thisLabelDefaultText = thisLabel.html();
            thisLabel.addClass('file-input-label');
            thisLabel.on("click", function (e) {
                thisInput.trigger("click");
                e.preventDefault() 
            });
            thisInput.on('change',thisLabel, function () {
                console.log("Input used: " + thisInput.data("field"));
                if (thisInput.val()) {
                    thisLabel.html(thisInput.val());
                } else {
                    thisLabel.html(thisLabelDefaultText);
                };
            });
        };
    });
};
activateFileSelection();
```

And live example : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/csc5bphy/